# Reducing width of inline block element causes additional page to be generated by Chrome in resulting PDF

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf, printing

In the following HTML,

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a simple `div` element which I am styling as follows:

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

@page {
    margin: 0;
}
```

When I use the PDF printing functionality in Chrome, the resulting PDF is one page, and the `div` element takes up the entirety of the height and width of the page as I expect.

However, when I change the `width` property in the CSS rule targeting the `div` element to anything less than `100vw`, while keeping the height at `100vh`, the resulting PDF is two pages long which doesn't make sense.

Why does this occur and how can I set the width of the `div` without it causing a new page to be generated in the resulting PDF?

Answer (score 0):

The css `box-sizing` [box-sizing - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) can't be inherited by default, so you  need to add the following css

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

or set border width zero